# How can I scrape some data in Python using a *.php in the Netwotk tab inspection of Chrome

Tags: python, php, networking, web-scraping

I'm rather new in using Python.
I want collect arrays in "data" as output by means of this file "get_data.php"

[image]

If I open the URL of that XHR the page is empty.

Can I scrape those data with GET/POST method of Python Requests library?
I would avoid Selenium, because I don't like passing through the browser

This is a POST request:[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4vCC.png)
So I used this part of code: [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0zsx.png)

But I obtain the response content wit no sense:   b'\x83b\x00\x00\x04\xfe\x9b[\xea/_XX\xba:X)"\xa2\x.........

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library called [requests](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/).

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://example.com/get_data.php")
```

If the simple code does not work for you, then you have to send the request with header data as same as the browser. Click on the Headers tab for the request information.

Comment: Thank you, I did a POST request (like the request in the network tab) with all "request headers", but I can't obtain the content of the response

Comment: Delete "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br" from the header. It encodes the response, so you can't read it.

Comment: Thanks, now I can get the response, but with arrays empty...   I don't know if I don't see the children or am I doing something wrong in the request (headers or data) ?